# How to add add priority fee on anchor cli

Tags: anchor, solana-program, deploy, priority-fees

I am trying to deploy a program and read that is possible to add priority fee to the deploy transactions.

If possible how to do it. I am using

```
anchor deploy
```

Comment: Solana CLI has an open PR for adding priority fees. Anchor will probably add it once the former is merged. For the time being, you can try out Solana Playground for deploying your programs as it merged priority fees recently https://twitter.com/acheroncrypto/status/1768423506843168994?t=N1TxcxNhNIJ4dChFUOVxzg&s=19

Comment: Great gonna check Solana Playground